# How to change favicon when tab page changes in c# browser?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, favicon

I am creating a browser in c#. I want to add favicon in  every tabpages according to the browser address. I have the following code that returns me the favicon of the current address.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("http://" + new Uri(getCurrentBrowser().Address.ToString()).Host + "/favicon.ico"));
Icon icon = new Icon(memorystream);
imageList.Images.Add(icon.ToBitmap());
tabControl.SelectedTab.ImageIndex = 0; // sets favicon in current tab
```

My problem with the last line of the code. How do I set different favicon for different tab? How do I keep track which favicon belongs to which tab?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took me sometime. But I figured it out. For anyone who is facing the same problem, here is the solution.

```
public void favicon()
{
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("http://" + new Uri(getCurrentBrowser().Address.ToString()).Host + "/favicon.ico"));
        Icon icon = new Icon(memorystream);
        string i = Convert.ToString(myimg.Images.Count);
        myimg.Images.Add(i, icon.ToBitmap());
        tabControl.ImageList = myimg;
        tabControl.SelectedTab.ImageIndex = myimg.Images.Count - 1;
}
```

Call it in the browser title change method. and `getCurrentBrowser()` returns the current browser. Here is the code:

```
// get current browser
   public ChromiumWebBrowser getCurrentBrowser()
   {
       return (ChromiumWebBrowser)tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
   }
```